# With Google AppsScript Triggers - how can I tell which trigger was hit?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-calendar-api

I have added a trigger that will run a script every time a user adds an event to a calendar. It works fine.
I have to install a different trigger for each calendar I want to check.
I want to know which calendar was updated as different actions happen depending on the calendar. 
How can I retrieve the calendarId that caused the trigger to run?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by myself:

```
function getCalendarId(e){
  Logger.log("everything: " + e);
  Logger.log("calendarId: " + e.calendarId);
}
```